# Work with custom data type haskell

Tags: haskell, custom-data-type

I've this data type `data List x = LT [(x,[String])]`
and I'm been trying to create a function that would add a new element to the `List`.

For example by using function `add`:

`add ('a', ["1","2"]) [('x',["1"])]`

result would be:

`[('x',["1"]), ('a', ["1","2"])]`

It doesn't matter what is the order.
I've tried a lot, still don't understand much.

This is what I tried

```
`add:: Ord a => a -> List a -> List a 
 add _ (LT[]) = empty 
 add x (LT(y:ys))
     | belongs x (LT(y:ys)) = (LT(y:ys)) 
     | otherwise = (LT(y:ys)) ++ (LT(x))`
```

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you not just use ++? You are already using a Haskell list in your definition, so if you gave `('a', ["1","2"])` as a list, e.g. `[('a', ["1","2"])]`, then your function can just take the two lists, use ++, and return a new list that will contain both. 

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html

Comment: @DannyWilson, sorry probably I didn't formulate the question right, the add function receives element and a List (LT) and not exactly a tuple and a list, so ++ doesn't work.

Comment: You example should then be `add 'a' [('x', ["1"])]`. It's not clear what list should be associated with `'a'` in the result, though. Is it just the same list associated with the previous last value, but with one more number-turned-string added to the end?

Answer (score 1):

As Danny Wilson pointed out, you can use the `++` operator to concatenate two lists:

```
ghci> [1,2] ++ [3,4]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Do keep in mind that both sides of a `++` need to be lists, and you have one list and one non-list, so you'll need to make one of those into a list first.

I have a wild guess based on some details in your phrasing that you are having trouble with data constructors.  A `List x` does not take the form

```
[('x',["1"])]
```

But rather

```
LT [('x',["1"])]
```

which is just a regular list "wrapped" with the `LT` *constructor*.  If you want to write a function `add`, you need to pattern match on this constructor.  Every value of type `List` "starts with" `LT`:

```
add :: (x, [String]) -> List x -> List x
add elem (LT list) = LT (...)
```

(You need to fill in the `...` yourself)

You only need to put the `LT` when you need to access the guts of the type, the list inside.  So this function returns the list unmodified, and it does not need the `LT`:

```
doNothing :: List x -> List x
doNothing a = a
```

But as soon as you need to know that a `List x` is represented by a list of some stuff, you need to use the `LT` constructor.

Does that help?

Comment: It kind of does, 
here is what I tried to do `add:: Ord a => a -> List a -> List a`
   `add _ (LT[]) = empty`
   `add x (LT(y:ys))`
   `| belongs x (LT(y:ys)) = (LT(y:ys))`
   `| otherwise = (LT(y:ys)) ++ (LT(x))`

But it doesn't work (`belongs` and `empty` are two functions I made).

Comment: Yeah, there's a type error at `LT(x)`, because `x` isn't a list.  Try `LT [x]` (making it into a one-element list first, and we never needed parentheses there).   Note that the way this is specified, adding something to an empty list will always be empty, which ... doesn't quite seem right.  But your first goal should be to get it to compile without type errors.

Comment: Oh there's another type error when you say `(LT ...) ++ (LT ...)`. `++` takes two haskell lists, not two of your `List`s (which are made with `LT`).  You need to put the `++` *inside* the `LT` constructor.

Comment: Like this `(LT (y:ys) ++ x)`??

Comment: `LT ((y:ys) ++ [x])`.  Function application (what `LT` is doing) is tighter than any other operator, so it only applies to `(y:ys)` and not the `++ x` part.  And we needed to make a singleton list out of `x` like I keep saying

Comment: Still doesn't work... this is what shows up `Couldn't match expected type ‘[(a, [String])]’ with actual type ‘a’`.

Comment: Yeah, your type signature is wrong.  You don't seem to have any idea what you're doing, you're just trying things randomly.   Back up to earlier in a tutorial (e.g. [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)) or ask your professor for help if you're in a class.  This problem is currently too hard for you.

Comment: Yup, I've been trying to figure it out using that book learnyouahaskell.com, but it came to random tries, type signature was given by the professor as the data type, just wanted to figure it out to work with data types and how I can "access" the elements in it. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Just to clear things up, your data type and type signature are very different things. Your data type is `data List x = LT [(x,[String])]`, which defines the data you want to process, kind of like an object in OO. Think of it like this, you have the data type `data Circle = Float Float Float`, which defines a circle with 3 float values. Then, when you wish to operate on it, you write a function. The first line is the Type Definition. So, e.g., `addInts :: Int -> Int -> Int`, which takes two ints and returns an Int. If you're unsure about the type, leave the line out...

Comment: Let Haskell guess, which most of the time it will be able to. This will get you past your error, then call `:t addInts`, and it will tell you the type signature of `addInt :: Int -> Int -> Int`.